# get Javassist MethodInfo from Apache BCEL JavaClass

Tags: java, javassist, javaagents, bcel

I recently wanted to make this github project[Whyline](https://github.com/amyjko/whyline) to use library instead of writing own code. This project has a javaagent and I am stucked in the whyline/tracing/ClassInstrumener.java class. So I found out that Apache BCEL and Javassist has classes that can replace existing code but I do not know how to replace this to fit the for loop

```
for (MethodInfo method : classfile.getDeclaredMethods()) {
```

classfile is an instance of org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass but MethodInfo is an instance of javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo

Answer (score 0):

Can use

```
for (Method method : classfile.getMethods()) {
```

which is under the same BCEL library